# Ruby-On-Rails Database Setup Using Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am having a problem on ruby on rails during database installation following the tutorial from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-active-records.htm

First, I created a new project using the code below,

```
C:\projects>rails new libray
```

It created the project successfully. I followed the database installation using **mysql** then changed the **database.yml** content.

From code (Original value from fresh created project)

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

To new code:

```
development:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_development
   username: root
   password: 1234
   host: localhost

test:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_test
   username: root
   password: 1234
   host: localhost

production:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_production
   username: root
   password: 1234
   host: localhost
```

Next is to create **active records** using the code:

```
C:\projects>library>rails generate model book
```

But I got the following error.

[Click to see error in img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfaLa.png)

I am new to **Ruby on Rails**, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `development:` remove indent, look how, `test: and production:` is defined

Comment: @mrvncaragay already updated my question above, but still got a problem

Comment: please remove tab space in database.yml

Comment: @ChaudharyPrakash question already edited, and I found the answer by creating new project using -d mysql

Comment: ok..good..but you don't need to create new project you also change database.yml its working fine

Comment: @ChaudharyPrakash at first I had a problem due to default db was sqlite, I think I only need to fix my indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to have some syntax error in the `database.yml` file. **The `yml` files follows strict indentation and syntax**, try this code with indentation.

No need to take `adapter, username, password, host and port` in every environment.

You can create a `default` and can re-use those values.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: library_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: library_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: library_production
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the code below when creating the project.

```
appliction_dir>rails new project_name -d mysql
```

The content of **database.yaml** will use the **mysql** configuration.
Then all you have to do, is to change the **username** and **password**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that** You were right in your configuration but you used only mysql in adapter
it should be `adapter: mysql2` instead

Comment: yes, thank you so much for your answer. when I created new project the default adapter is mysql2